# How to sort the list of checkboxes on loading and on click (first marked alphabetically and then the rest)?

Tags: javascript

There is a list of checkboxes

```html
<ul>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a[]" value="a1">
<label for="a1">Alex</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a2" name="a[]" value="a2">
<label for="a2">Mike</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a3" name="a[]" value="a3">
<label for="a3">Bob</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a4" name="a[]" value="a4">
<label for="a4">Anton</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

It is necessary that when the code is loaded, the list should be sorted by the value in the label by asc order
And when one or more elements are selected, so that these checkboxes move up (also sorted by asc order) and first the selected records go by asc order, and then the unselected records by asc order

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the `label` by checking if it's `checkbox` checked or not, then sort with its `textContent` with the `localeCompare` method, which sorts the text.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
        sortChecboxes()
    })
})

const sortChecboxes = () => {
  const result = [...list.children].sort((li1, li2) => {
    const label1 = li1.querySelector('label');
    const checkbox1 = li1.querySelector('input');
    const label2 = li2.querySelector('label');
    const checkbox2 = li2.querySelector('input');
    const compareText = label1.textContent.trim().localeCompare(label2.textContent.trim())
    return checkbox1.checked && checkbox2.checked ? compareText : checkbox2.checked ? 1 : checkbox1.checked ? -1 : compareText
    
  });
  result.forEach(i => list.append(i))

}

sortChecboxes()
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a[]" value="a1">
<label for="a1">Alex</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a2" name="a[]" value="a2">
<label for="a2">Mike</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a3" name="a[]" value="a3">
<label for="a3">Bob</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="a4" name="a[]" value="a4">
<label for="a4">Anton</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Multivariable Sort

We can use `.sort()` to first compare `checked` then compare `textContent`

```js
function drawList(){
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  const itemArray = [...list.children];
  
  const sortedArray = itemArray.sort((a,b) => {
    // First sort by checbox
    let aChecked = a.querySelector('input').checked;
    let bChecked = b.querySelector('input').checked;
    if (aChecked && !bChecked) return -1;
    if (!aChecked && bChecked) return 1;
    
    // If both are checked/not checked compare by textContent
    let aText = a.querySelector('label').textContent;
    let bText = b.querySelector('label').textContent;    
    return aText > bText ? 1 : -1;
  })

  list.innerHTML = '';
  list.append(...sortedArray);
}

const checkboxCollection = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
const checkboxArray = [...checkboxCollection];
checkboxArray.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', drawList))

drawList();
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a[]" value="a1">
    <label for="a1">Alex</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a2" name="a[]" value="a2">
    <label for="a2">Mike</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a3" name="a[]" value="a3">
    <label for="a3">Bob</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a4" name="a[]" value="a4">
    <label for="a4">Anton</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Split and Sort

- Split the list to checked and unchecked element arrays
- Sort each array by `textContent`
- Append the sorted checked elements then the sorted unchecked elements

```js
function sortElements(elementArray) {
  return elementArray.sort((a,b) => {
    let aContent = a.querySelector('label').textContent
    let bContent = b.querySelector('label').textContent
    return aContent < bContent ? -1 : 1
  })
}

function drawList(){
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  const itemArray = [...list.children];
  
  const checked = itemArray.filter(item => item.querySelector('input').checked)
  const notChecked = itemArray.filter(item => !item.querySelector('input').checked)
  
  const sortedChecked = sortElements(checked);
  const sortedUnchecked = sortElements(notChecked);
  
  list.innerHTML = '';
  list.append(...sortedChecked, ...sortedUnchecked);
}

const checkboxCollection = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
const checkboxArray = [...checkboxCollection];
checkboxArray.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', drawList))

drawList();
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a[]" value="a1">
    <label for="a1">Alex</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a2" name="a[]" value="a2">
    <label for="a2">Mike</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a3" name="a[]" value="a3">
    <label for="a3">Bob</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a4" name="a[]" value="a4">
    <label for="a4">Anton</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that since we filter the array twice, we're iterating one more time than we need to. If you care about that extra iteration, the solution below filters in one iteration.

```js
function sortElements(elementArray) {
  return elementArray.sort((a,b) => {
    let aContent = a.querySelector('label').textContent
    let bContent = b.querySelector('label').textContent
    return aContent < bContent ? -1 : 1
  })
}

function splitByChecked(elementArray) {
  const output = {
    checked: [],
    notChecked: [],
  }
  elementArray.forEach(element => {
    let checkbox = element.querySelector('input')
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      output.checked.push(element)
    } else {
      output.notChecked.push(element)
    }
  })
  return output;
} 

function drawList(){
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  const itemArray = [...list.children];
  const {checked, notChecked} = splitByChecked(itemArray);
  const sortedChecked = sortElements(checked);
  const sortedUnchecked = sortElements(notChecked);
  list.innerHTML = '';
  list.append(...sortedChecked, ...sortedUnchecked);
}

const checkboxCollection = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
const checkboxArray = [...checkboxCollection];
checkboxArray.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', drawList))

drawList();
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a1" name="a[]" value="a1">
    <label for="a1">Alex</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a2" name="a[]" value="a2">
    <label for="a2">Mike</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a3" name="a[]" value="a3">
    <label for="a3">Bob</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a4" name="a[]" value="a4">
    <label for="a4">Anton</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```